# Input password in Win32 console application

Tags: winapi

I've developed a little routine to input a password in a Win32 console:

```
wstring inputPassword()
{
    HANDLE hStdIn, hStdOut;
    hStdIn = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
    hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    DWORD dwOldConsoleMode;
    GetConsoleMode( hStdIn, &dwOldConsoleMode );
    SetConsoleMode( hStdIn, dwOldConsoleMode & ~(DWORD)(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT) );
    vector<COORD> coords;
    auto getCoord = [&]() -> COORD
    {
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hStdOut, &csbi );
        return csbi.dwCursorPosition;
    };
    auto revertConsolePos = [&]( bool pop )
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdOut, coords.back() );
        if( pop )
            coords.pop_back();
    };
    auto printConsole = [&]( wchar_t ch )
    {
        DWORD dwWritten;
        WriteConsoleW( hStdOut, &ch, 1, &dwWritten, nullptr );
    };
    wstring pass;
    for( ; ; )
    {
        wchar_t ch;
        DWORD dwRead;
        ReadConsoleW( hStdIn, &ch, 1, &dwRead, nullptr );
        if( ch == L'\r' )
            break;
        if( ch != L'\b' )
            pass += ch,
            coords.emplace_back( getCoord() ),
            printConsole( L'*' );
        else
            if( pass.length() )
                pass.resize( pass.length() - 1 ),
                revertConsolePos( false ),
                printConsole( L' ' ),
                revertConsolePos( true );
    }
    SetConsoleMode( hStdIn, dwOldConsoleMode );
    return pass;
}
```

Unfortunatly this doesn't work perfectly since the console-positions-vecor might not be up to date when the console is resized. How can I update my console positions according to a window resize?

Comment: Don't mix the console API with C++' I/O streams library. Also, please show a [mcve]. As it stands there's no easy way for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I changed the code to use WriteConsoleW, but I don't see any reason for that the former "cout <<" shouldn't work. The example couldn't be stripped further.

Comment: A [mcve] needs to be minimal **and** complete.

Comment: I removed the error-handling.

Comment: A standard trick to implement a backspace is to output `"\b \b"`

Comment: @HansPassant: Doesn't work across line breaks. My solution works across line breaks as long as the window isn't resized.